# How can we use up our Flex Spending Account (FSA) before the end of the year?

Tags: united-states, healthcare, fsa, eligible-expenses

My husband and I signed up for a Flex Spending Account for the first time this past year.  We've got about $100 left over now, in mid-November, and I've been told that money will disappear if we don't use it by the end of the year.  I don't anticipate needing any visits to the doctor, and I know it can be used for other things, but I'm not entirely sure what.

What can we do to make the most of our FSA $100 before it goes away?  What can a Flex Spending account be used for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some eligible expenses include:
- Sunscreen (SPF 30 and greater) 
- Band Aids
- Tylenol and Advil
- Mileage driven for medical care (at a rate of 24 cents/mile)
- Vision expenses (glasses, contacts, contact solution, eye drops, etc)
- Chiropractor visits
- Airborne
- Anti-decongestants

You should be able to go to a local drug store and see what items are eligible to be purchased through with your Flexible Spending Account (ask at the counter).

We also have a website that only sells FSA eligible items and ships directly to your home if you want to check out that option.  Please let me know if you have any more Flexible Spending Account Questions or need more ideas.

Comment: A trip to the chiropractor, eye doc visits and a new pair of glasses used up the last of our FSA.  Thanks for the advice!  I do need to comment, though, that when I finally tracked down our FSA paperwork, it specifically excluded sunscreen.  I guess the bottom line is that you need to check with your plan.

Comment: OTC medications have been removed from the FSA lists as of 2011.

Comment: @N West - not exactly - to use an FSA, you need a doctor's prescription. Silly to go to doc to get aspirin, but if you happen to see her for something, not a bad idea to ask for a few prescriptions (for OTC items.)